# How to create Button/Switch-Like Tile where you can step on it and change its value?

Tags: c#, algorithms, game-development, xna

If the player steps on a Button-Tile when its true, it becomes false. If the player steps on a Button-Tile when it is false, it becomes true.

The problem is, when the player stands on (intersects) the Button-Tile, it will keep updating the condition. So, from true, it becomes false. Because its false and the player intersects it, it becomes true again. True-false-true-false and so on.

I use ElapsedGameTime to make the updating process slower, and the player can have a chance to change the Button to true or false.

However, it's not the solution I was looking for. Is there any other way to make it keep in False/True condition while the Player is standing on the Button tile?

Answer (score 4):

The condition is wrong: do not update the state when the player stands on the tile, update the state when the player *enters* the tile. This way they can stand on a tile as long as they want with no change.

Answer (score 0):

When the player enters the tile, set an Entered flag for that tile to true. As long as this flag is true, don't update the Button-tile status.

When the player exits the tile, set the Entered flag to false.